# iOS Application preferences backup

Tags: ios, backup, preferences

I remove my app from device and want to have the same info stored in NSUserDefaults after reinstall (spent long time) as I have before.

Is application preferences backed up with iCloud and(or) iTunes and restore after reinstall application?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.i think it is not possible to preferences backup with iCloud and(or) iTunes still now.

Answer (score 0):

Store your preferences in [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html), it'll be persistent when your app is uninstalled or system restore.